# XSL output XML with no prefix without using the default namespace?

Tags: xml, xslt, xml-namespaces

I have an XSL where I need to generate output along the lines of this:

```
<moo xmlns="http://api.example.com">
    <foo>1358944586848</foo>
    <bar>
        <a>1</a>
        <b>2</b>
        <c>3</c>
    </bar>
</moo>
```

I could do it like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://api.example.com">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:element name="moo">
            <!-- and so on -->
```

However, I kind of hate using the xsl prefix in my xsl files cause I feel it clutters it up a lot. Selecting with XPath is easy anyways since you can set `xpath-default-namespace` to whatever you're transforming from if needed. But there is no `element-default-namespace` available as far as I can see, so how can I generate the wanted output in a good way?

I know I can do this:

```
<stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <template match="/">
        <element name="moo" namespace="http://api.example.com">
            <!-- and so on -->
```

But then I have to set this namespace explicitly on every single element I create, or they will end up with the XSL namespace instead. So is there a clean way to create elements with a certain namespace (without a prefix) and not touching the default namespace of the xsl file?

---

**Update:**

Figured maybe `namespace-alias` could do something, but can't figure out how to use it. Tried this, but doesn't seem to make any difference in the output at all:

```
<stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:out="http://api.example.com">

<namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="out" result-prefix=""/>

    <template match="/">
        <element name="out:moo">
            <!-- and so on -->
```

The `namespace-alias` thing probably isn't doing what I think it is :p

***The final solution I used, based on JLRishe's answer***

*remove-prefixes.xsl*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <template match="/">
        <variable name="result">
            <next-match />
        </variable>
        <apply-templates select="$result" mode="remove-prefixes" />
    </template>

    <template match="*" priority="1" mode="remove-prefixes">
        <element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
            <apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="remove-prefixes" />
        </element>
    </template>
    <template match="@*|node()" mode="remove-prefixes">
        <copy>
            <apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="remove-prefixes" />
        </copy>
    </template>

</stylesheet>
```

*subject.xsl*

```
<!-- snip -->
<import href="remove-prefixes.xsl" />
<!-- snip -->
```

Comment: Regarding your update and `namespace-alias` - the only thing which your sample might achieve is that the `moo` is written out as being in the `http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform` namespace. I haven't ever tried it with the empty prefix and I'm not sure if this is actually a valid use of `namespace-alias` (haven't checked).

Comment: Seems you can use `#default` as the value of the `namespace-alias` attributes as well. Still doesn't seem to do what I was hoping it would though...

Comment: I'll add an edit in a few secs which may do what you want... try it.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend loosing the "xsl:" prefix. Better, use good code formatting. Namespaces have the sole purpose of disambiguation. Hiding the prefix often leads to confusion when working with two different vocabularies -- which is exactly your case. Often the source XML document could have element names such as "output", "element", "attribute", "variable". In such cases if the :xsl:" prefix is stripped,  it becomes difficult to distinguish which is the source xml document and which is the XSLT stylesheet. Errors, annoying and time-consuming, could happen.

Comment: I don't think `namespace-alias` is going to do what you're hoping.  It can produce your output with a default namespace, but that default namespace would be "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" (since that's the default namespace of the XSLT).

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev The source document usually has a namespace and I can use a prefix for that. If it has no namespace I can set `xpath-default-namespace=""` and queries work fine. I like to do it this way because what I mainly look at is the XSL and I therefore like to keep that as much clutter free as possible. Might just be me who like it this way though :p

Comment: @Svish, I deeply respect your personal preferences. However, if this code is intended not only for your eyes, it would be more readable to everyone else, if you left the "xsl:" prefix intact. Another important factor is that some XSLT IDEs only do syntax hi-lighting if the prefix "xsl:" is used -- they stop doing this even if another prefix (such as "xslt:") is used.

Comment: Your points are good! Maybe I'll switch. We'll see :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing you could do is capture the entire result of the XSL in a variable, and then blank out its prefixes at the end:

```
<stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                          xmlns:p="http://api.example.com">
  <output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <template match="/">
    <variable name="result">
      <p:moo>
        <apply-templates />
      </p:moo>
    </variable>
    <apply-templates select="$result" mode="removePrefix" />
  </template>

  <template match="root">
    <p:something hello="hi">
      <element name="p:somethingelse" />
    </p:something>
  </template>

  <template match="p:*" mode="removePrefix">
    <element name="{local-name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
      <apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="removePrefix" />
    </element>
  </template>

  <template match="@* | node()" mode="removePrefix">
    <copy>
      <apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </copy>
  </template>
</stylesheet>
```

When run on this input:

```
<root>
  <top />
</root>
```

it produces:

```
<moo xmlns="http://api.example.com">
  <something hello="hi">
    <somethingelse />
  </something>
</moo>
```

Comment: Actually this sort of solves it. My goal was not to avoid prefixes in XSL code, but in the output. Sorry if that wasn't clear. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Svish Thank you very much for accepting my answer. If you would like to show your final version, please add that to your question text rather than replacing the content of my post.

Comment: Figured it would be more appropriate to have it in the answer so i appended it there, but no worries. I see you moved it already :)

Answer (score 1):

The `xmlns:xsl`-approach is really the "standard" day, and I suppose that the designers of XSL had that in mind.

Remember that you're allowed to directly mix XML fragments into XSL. From that point of view, your approach with the `xsl:element` arguably adds much more noise and clutter than what you are trying to eliminate with your "element-default-namespace".

So, I'd do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://api.example.com">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <moo>
            <!-- and so on -->
```

**Edit:**

The following with `namespace-alias` might work:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns="http://api.example.com">

    <namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="xsl" result-prefix="#default"/>

    <template match="/" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <element name="moo">
            <!-- etc -->
```

Or like this:

```
<stylesheet version="2.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="api" 
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:api="http://api.example.com">

    <namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="#default" result-prefix="api"/>

    <template match="/">
        <element name="moo">
            <!-- etc -->
```

Comment: Problem with sticking XML fragments directly in there is that you have to define the name of the element two places rather than one. Might seem like a minor issue, but I've found it much easier to keep it in one place. Also, since you're using the default namespace here anyways, both `<moo>` and `<xsl:element name="moo">` would work fine.

Comment: @Svish, having it on the end as well actually is a plus for me: it gives much better readability since I see what element ends where, which is not the case with `xsl:element`. The larger the fragments are which you are working with, the more important this becomes. I use `xsl:element` only when I don't have a static name and have to compute it on the fly.

Comment: Well, I might be a bit colored with a very annoying and slow tool we have to use in this case where it's much faster to correct an attribute value than two element names. Cause when I change the opening tag the tool wants to tell me that there are unclosed/unmatched/wrong xml here and it's very slow in telling me so :p

Comment: See your point though! Your solution still uses the default namespace which is what I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: Re your edit: Would have to add the xmlns to every template element then?

Comment: @Svish, yeah - of yourse you can also use the same approach with the default being the XSL on the root, but I'm afraid that you output will then use the prefix. Maybe that can be fixed with `exclude-result-prefixes` though...

Comment: Tried both the namespace-alias versions and neither seemed to do anything, which is a bit annoying cause it looked promising. And in my head it would kind of make sense if that's what would happen...

Comment: @Svish, yeah - I guess that's not the use case it was designed for. ;) - So in summary I'd still suggest to go with the plain and simple approach using the `xsl` prefix for the XSL stuff.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the same way as you about the cluttering, especially if I have stylesheets where the overwhelming majority of elements is in the XSL namespace, not in the target namespace. The solution is simple: Give the output elements a prefix rather than the XSL elements:

```
<stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:o="http://api.example.com">

    <template match="/">
        <o:moo>
            <!-- and so on -->
```

Comment: This looks wrong. For it to work it should be `<element name="o:moo">`. The problem then is that the output ends up with the `o` prefix, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: @Svish: Oh, yeah, you're right - I was trying to say something different. Thanks for the hint. Changed the answer accordingly.

Comment: This would work, but the output would still end up with an `o:` prefix.

Comment: I usually don't care about this. Any XML parser consuming the file should get it right one way or the other. But you're right, I once had problems where someone else threw some SVG output at a web application that probably wasn't XHTML and got into problems.

Comment: Yeah, my output usually has prefixes, but in this case it's going to a rather old 3rd-party system that likes to be difficult :)