# remove default namespace in xml file using xslt

Tags: sql, xml, xslt, soa

This my part of input xml file to my procedure,

```xml
<Appl xmlns=''>
    <Name>
        <Fore>bbb</Fore>
    </Name>
    <Name>
        <Fore>bbb</Fore>
    </Name>
</Appl>
```

I am just updating the xml in procedure to different value using this update operation,

```sql
UPDATE table SET column = UPDATEXML(column,'//Appl/Name[1]/Fore/text()','XXX');
UPDATE table SET column = UPDATEXML(column,'//Appl/Name[2]/Fore/text()','YYY');
```

but my output is added **xmlns=''** in each tag,

```xml
<Appl xmlns=''>
    <Name xmlns=''>
        <Fore xmlns=''>XXX</Fore>
    </Name>
    <Name xmlns=''>
        <Fore xmlns=''>YYY</Fore>
    </Name>
</Appl>
```

How to remove extra `xmlns=''` in each tags.

Comment: Could you show us more than just a part? The `xmlns=''` is probably there to say that the element does not belong to its parent's element namespace.

Comment: Hi michale see below entier xml..

Comment: Input xml:
<inc xmlns="http://xmsls.us.com/esev/eer/v7/yesterday">
<Appl xmlns=''>
<Terc>
<Name>
<Fore>bbb</Fore>
</Name>
<Name>
<Fore>bbb</Fore>
</Name>
</Terc>
</Appl>

<Qar xmlns=''>
<Wer>
<error>
<status>bbb</status>
</error>
<error>
<status>bbb</status>
</error>
</Wer>
</Qar>

Comment: Output xml:
<inc xmlns="http://xmsls.us.com/esev/eer/v7/yesterday">
<Appl xmlns=''>
<Terc xmlns=''>
<Name xmlns=''>
<Fore xmlns=''>bbb</Fore>
</Name>
<Name>
<Fore xmlns=''>bbb</Fore>
</Name>
</Terc>
</Appl>

<Qar xmlns=''>
<Wer xmlns=''>
<error xmlns=''>
<status xmlns=''>bbb</status>
</error xmlns=''>
<error>
<status xmlns=''>bbb</status>
</error>
</Wer>
</Qar>

Comment: Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question instead. If you are using a XSLT stylesheet (this part is not clear to me), include it too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [XSL output XML with no prefix without using the default namespace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14480173/xsl-output-xml-with-no-prefix-without-using-the-default-namespace)